# Crystal Reports Crosstab with multiple row fields(attributes)

Tags: stored-procedures, crystal-reports, crosstab

I'm designing a business analysis report using Crystal Report XI and oracle stored procedure as data source. Report contains a crosstab with one row (on the left) and summarized values under selling station names. 
Requirement is to have multiple attribute columns on left like Product ID, Product Name, Product Color, Product Size, Product Sold Date etc and at the end, summarized values. What I've done so far is a crosstab with only one column at left and then summarized values.
Here is the sample of crosstab as required. 
[image]

I've done plenty of R&D but didn't find any appropriate solution.

The output of report is required to match the format provided by business user.

Comment: No one got a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution I devised is here:

Crosstab is used to aggregate and jointly display the distribution of two or more variables by tabulating their results against one dimension. Problem was how to increase the number of dimensions. Since this is against logic of crosstab, so I modified my stored-procedure and created one single string by concatenating the dimensions and created a crosstab against it. These dimensions are separated by a delimiter '~' or you can use some other for better readability.